# MySQL Proxy with NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, mysql-proxy

I am trying to create a simple program that create a proxy between a MySQL-based application and a MySQL server.
Right now,my approach is to change the application to talk to MySQL at port 3065 and my proxy is a simple socket server whose listens to all requests and sending them to MySQL server. 

I wanted to change the architecture and I saw this page : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-proxy-scripting.html, In this page I have exactly what I need - read_query() and read_query_results(). 
And my main problem is - they are using LUA as the proxy`s scripting language,How can I use this API in NodeJS?

Comment: Are you familiar with DBSlayer?  It's a MySQL proxy that takes JSON at the front end, queries the database, and return JSON as the response.  It's the database layer used (and developed) by the New York Times.

Comment: will it helps me to "sit" between mysql and the application?

Comment: what do you need to achieve in your proxy? I'm planning to add mysql server protocol to my driver ( https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native/issues/32 )

Comment: Andrey,I create this to expriement with nodejs(net) and websockets.